# Can we set up a FTP Site using Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Totally new to FTP and Azure. So please excuse if the question sounds stupid.

Is there a way to set up FTP using Azure Web App service? Is it even possible? I am trying to avoid using a dedicated VM with IIS for setting up FTP.

All my search results in deployment of a web app using FTP, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for an option to install/configure FTP server on web apps? or Option to setup FTP deployment credentials on Azure Web App?

Comment: Well, you get FTP in App Service. It's normally used for deployments but obviously you could use it for anything. Only one set of credentials though :)

Comment: @juunas I cannot use the out of the box FTP service used for Deployments as I need to give the creds to the Customer and I don't wanna give mine. 
Basically, my end goal is to let the customer dump their files to Azure Blob, we don't want to expose blob directly, wanted to use FTP and then use a script to sync files b/w blob and file system.

Answer (score 2):

Since the out-of-the-box FTP for deployments is out of the question, then the answer is no.

App Service is quite strict in what ports you can listen to, and FTP(S) is not one of them.

What you could do is create a storage account where the customer can put their files, and then use scripts to copy the files from there. The customer could use File Storage or Blob Storage. File can be easier for end-users, since it is just a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set up FTP using Azure Web App service? Is it even
>   possible?

As I known, it's not possible to set up FTP service  via Azure Web App Service to reach your request. You can use Deployment Credentials to deploy your web App via FTP, but cannot use Web App to deploy FTP service.

According to your request, I suggest you can let your customers  use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) .

For more convenient to your customers, using scripts to using Azure Blob to upload/download file is not recommended. Azure Storage Explorer can let you access Azure Blob like FTP. You can create different Access keys for customers and they can use their own keys to access the Blob.

If you don't want take this solution, I think that it's necessary to set up a FTP server via Azure VM.